# Depth map (2d+z) algorithm or software

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, face-recognition

I'm searching for Depth map algorithm for action scrip 3 (or some other language).
My goal is to generate depth map for static image on run time.
I have fount this example http://kode80.com/2009/06/29/papervision-zbuffer-and-dof/, i didn't have the time to investigate it's code but i have the filling its working only with 3d models.
Worst viable option is server side technology that does the work.

**Extended description:**
I have a task to develop flash application where 3d rotation of a head is simulated by a 2d image uploaded by the user.
There are some japan guys that have managed to do that (http://hairtry.jp/), but the technology that they are using is server side. It generates swf fail with precisely coped eyes and image for the depth map of the uploaded picture. I can't find out what is the sever side technology that they are using so I'm searching for any posible workarounds.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, 
Chavdar Slavov

Answer (score 0):

your easiest solution would be to use a 3d engine, Paper vision seems to be getting out dated, theres a lot of documents on how to use, and tutorials but again not much has been happening with them lately. i suggest Away3d "www.away3d.com" they seem up to date.

for what your asking it is possible to do this 100% in flash but to create a 3d head at runtime and fill the face with hieght maps this is possible, you would need to look at bitmap manipulation.i dont think this is an easy task, what you should learn first is how to add an image to a spheric surface dynamically than look into height mapping by converting certain coulours from the image into different levels of depth i must say im sure this is advanced stuff, i manged to animate a  globe that was this same method it looks dodgy but it gives you some source code in the FLA

http://www.ffiles.com/flash/animations/globe_animation_3496.html 
The above link will allow you to download my source files, the animation it self is a scrolling image but i used Actionscript to give the globe depth and a sheric look

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't open the file because the required version for it is CS5.5 .
But anyway.. I'm investigating the opportunities offered by couple of 3d engines, but doubt that will give good results. The mapping probably should be very precise.

The option that I had in mind was to use this technique http://blog.yoz.sk/2010/05/pixel-bender-displacement-map-fakes-3d-effect/ . It can be implemented with PixelBender or with the as3 class DisplacementMapFilter. But since i don't have way to generate the depth map for the user image, this method is off the table.

Comment: you can implent this method if your confident enough, i have only mearly scraped the surface of displacemnet maps in as2, that link is similiar to my own dodgy project. a 3d engine for what your trying to do wouldnt work unless you download a 3d model face object file and map it in flash and a 3d engine but the head might look weird at times when your mapping it.